# Django - Invalid filter bleach

Tags: python, django

I'm migrating to "bleach", I followed all the step in the turoial but I had an error when I call: `{{ post.content|bleach }}` in the html. I'm using Django version 1.8. Also in my admin it didn't recognized my CKeditor.

The error message in the page is:

```
Request Method: GET
Exception Value:    Invalid filter: 'bleach'
```

In the server's log I got:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/wpage/urls.py:26: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Default value of 'RedirectView.permanent' will change from True to False in Django 1.9. Set an explicit value to silence this warning.
  url(r'^.*/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/blog/')),
```

Here are some of my files:

setting.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
    'django_bleach',
)
...
BLEACH_ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES = ['href', 'title', 'style']
BLEACH_ALLOWED_STYLES = [
    'font-family', 'font-weight', 'text-decoration', 'font-variant']
BLEACH_STRIP_TAGS = True
BLEACH_STRIP_COMMENTS = False
BLEACH_DEFAULT_WIDGET = 'ckeditor.widgets.CKEditorWidget'
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django_bleach.models import BleachField
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    content = BleachField()
```

base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load bleach_tags %}
...
```

post.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div> {{ post.content|bleach }} </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the `bleach_tags` in any templates where you use the `bleach` tag. Loading it in the parent template is not sufficient.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bleach_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div> {{ post.content|bleach }} </div>
```

The `RemovedInDjango19Warning` is a completely separate issue. As the message says, you can silence it by setting an explicit value:

```
RedirectView.as_view(url='/blog/', permanent=False)
```

The regex you are using, `'^.*/$'`, will permanently redirect **every** url ending with a slash to `/blog/`. I'm pretty sure you don't want to do that. I would remove that pattern (or at least set `permanent=False`) until you are happy it is working and are sure you want it to be permanent.